# Convert OpenGL shader to Metal (Swift) to be used in CIFilter

Tags: swift, opengl, shader, metal, cifilter

I'm quite new to `OpenGL`/`Metal` and I'm trying to understand some fundamental concepts.
Within our app, we are using `CIFilter` to filter videos. I saw a `WWDC` video from 2017 explaining that you can wrap `CIFilter` with `Metal` and use it as a regular filter.
I'm trying to understand how to convert this `OpenGL` video effect to `Metal` so I can use it as a reference point for future effects.

```
void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
float amount = sin(iTime) * 0.1;

// uv coords
vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;

amount *= 0.3;
float split = 1. - fract(iTime / 2.);
float scanOffset = 0.01;
vec2 uv1 = vec2(uv.x + amount, uv.y);
vec2 uv2 = vec2(uv.x, uv.y + amount);
if (uv.y > split) {
    uv.x += scanOffset;
    uv1.x += scanOffset;
    uv2.x += scanOffset;
}


float r = texture(iChannel0, uv1).r;
float g = texture(iChannel0, uv).g;
float b = texture(iChannel0, uv2).b;

fragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.);

}
```

Which produces:

[image]

After converting the `OpenGL` code to `Metal` I'm using the `CIFilter` wrapper to use it with `AVPlayerItem`:

```
class MetalFilter: CIFilter {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private let kernel: CIKernel
var inputImage: CIImage?

override init() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    kernel = try! CIKernel(functionName: "vhs", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
    super.init()
}


func outputImage() -> CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage else {return nil}
    let sourceSize = inputImage.extent.size
    let outputImage = kernel.apply(extent: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sourceSize.width, height: sourceSize.height), roiCallback: { index, destRect in
        return destRect
    }, arguments: [inputImage, NSNumber(value: Float(1.0 / sourceSize.width)), NSNumber(value: Float(1.0 / sourceSize.height)), NSNumber(value: 60.0)])

    return outputImage
   }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your `MetalFilter` implementation seems ok so far. What are you struggling with?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Hey Frank, thank you for replying. I'm trying to understand how to convert the OpenGL filter code to Metal (filename.metal file). Is there a guideline on how to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I gave it a try. Here's the kernel code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

    float4 vhs(sampler_h src, float time, float amount) {
        const float magnitude = sin(time) * 0.1 * amount;

        float2 greenCoord = src.coord(); // this is alreay in relative coords; no need to devide by image size

        const float split = 1.0 - fract(time / 2.0);
        const float scanOffset = 0.01;
        float2 redCoord = float2(greenCoord.x + magnitude, greenCoord.y);
        float2 blueCoord = float2(greenCoord.x, greenCoord.y + magnitude);
        if (greenCoord.y > split) {
            greenCoord.x += scanOffset;
            redCoord.x += scanOffset;
            blueCoord.x += scanOffset;
        }

        float r = src.sample(redCoord).r;
        float g = src.sample(greenCoord).g;
        float b = src.sample(blueCoord).b;

        return float4(r, g, b, 1.0);
    }

}}
```

And here some slight adjustments to `outputImage` in your filter:

```
override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else { return nil }

    // could be filter parameters
    let inputTime: NSNumber = 60
    let inputAmount: NSNumber = 0.3

    // You need to tell the kernel the region of interest of the input image,
    // i.e. what region of input pixels you need to read for a given output region.
    // Since you sample pixels to the right and below the center pixel, you need
    // to extend the ROI accordingly.
    let magnitude = CGFloat(sin(inputTime.floatValue) * 0.1 * inputAmount.floatValue)
    let inputExtent = inputImage.extent

    let roiCallback: CIKernelROICallback = { _, rect -> CGRect in
        return CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                      width: rect.width + (magnitude + 0.01) * inputExtent.width, // scanOffset
                      height: rect.height + magnitude * inputExtent.height)
    }

    return self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent,
                             roiCallback: roiCallback,
                             arguments: [inputImage, inputTime, inputAmount])
}
```

Comment: Hey Frank! Thank you so much! It works :) I can use it as a reference point now :) Superbe!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Core Image Metal filters and APIs are unfortunately very sparsely documented... Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on what/where to read about these subjects, so I can understand better how to convert the OpenGL filter to metal by myself? I'm trying to understand what are the "key phrases" I should be looking for. For example, I wasn't even sure if the word "Shader" fits here

Comment: "Filter Kernel" would be the right word here, I guess. Honestly the best (and almost only) source of documentation from Apple is the WWDC session you already watched. Maybe also check out the ones from 2018 that highlight some recent improvements. And there's this one PDF that's pretty helpful: https://developer.apple.com/metal/MetalCIKLReference6.pdf. And try pressing Cmd+Shift+O in Xcode and open `CIKernelMetalLib.h`. That's the header containing all CI-related additions to Metal and some documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I'll take a look, going to spend the weekend teaching my self those :) Also if may I ask: How much of actual performance gain do we get by using Metal with CIFilter compares to using OpenGL code within our app? If we'll place them side by side, does the Metal wrapper performance is noticeably better?

Comment: And one last small question regards this specific filter. I saw that `inputTime` was static within the `outputImage` property. Instead, I made it class property of `MetalFilter` and each frame I'm assigning its value by the composition time `filter.inputTime = NSNumber(value: CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime))`. Now I can actually see the filter lines going up and down (:D). Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: I guess it depends on the complexity of your filter pipeline. For this simple filter you probably won't notice the difference. But if you chain many filters together, the CI runtime can do some great optimization under the hood. Also, Apple is clearly deprecating OpenGL everywhere, so Metal is the way to go anyways.

Comment: It is! If you want to mimic the CI API as much as possible, you would declare the property like this `@objc dynamic var inputTime: NSNumber` and then set the value with `filter.setValue(CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime), forKey: "inputTime")`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again! Wishing you a great and restful weekend :)

Comment: Guys, this is amazing and helps me, being totally new to shaders, a lot!